# Stored Procedure error in codeigniter, A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 2014

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am getting this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 2014
            Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
            call usersInsert('test','test','test@test.com','1234567890','dddddssasasasasdddsss', @pusers_id)
            Filename: controllers/api/Users.php
            Line Number: 70
```

I am trying all possible solutions regarding this question on stackoverflow but can't solve it.
below is my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE usersInsert (
  IN puser_fname VARCHAR(50),
  IN puser_lname varchar(50),  
  IN puser_email varchar(100),
  IN puser_mobile varchar(20),
  IN pfb_token longtext,
  OUT pusers_id INT)


BEGIN

INSERT INTO users (
users_fname,
users_lname,
users_email,
users_mobile,
fb_token)
VALUES (puser_fname,
puser_lname,
puser_email,
puser_mobile,
 pfb_token);
set pusers_id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()); 
END //
```

Below is my Model function which is call to SP

```
public function insertUser($data){
     $success =  $this->db->query("call usersInsert('".$data['firstname']."','".$data['lastname']."','".$data['email']."','".$data['mobile_no']."','".$data['fbtoken']."', @pusers_id)");
            $this->db->trans_start();
            $success->next_result();
            $success->free_result();
            $query = $this->db->query('select @pusers_id as out_param');
            $this->db->trans_complete();
            return $query;
    }
```

please help thanks in advance

Comment: Where you stored this function? controller or model?

Comment: In the model i stored this function

Comment: 1. Why you're using a stored procedure? 2. Most likely the error happens elsewhere. What if you run any other query instead of this stored procedure? You should get this error either way

Comment: 1. I am using SP because of its time saving process.
2. Yes, I get this error in every stored procedure... some time its working and sometimes it's not working. SELECT query SP working perfectly but Insert and Update Query SP having problem... @YourCommonSense

Comment: @usersn 1. nowhere it's a time saver. A regular codeigniteters insert method is 100 times faster. 2. You don't understand what I am asking. But meh

Comment: Ohh Ya... i tried either way of MY_Model update function displaying this error as it is

Comment: I am using avenirer [link](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter) -MY_Model @YourCommonSense